# Error on Events Page: unknown block tag item

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I am VERY new to Apostrophe and have recently hit the error below.

I cloned the [Apostrophe Open Museum](https://github.com/apostrophecms/apostrophe-open-museum) repo and have been messing about with it for a few days locally to get a site setup... it was all going beautifully until the apostrophe-pieces-pages all decided to die on me.

This has happened to both this, as well as another "Testimonials" page that I have created. I have not changed the events-pages, events-widget or the events directories which contain the config.

Does anyone have any idea of where I even need to start debugging this? I've spent a couple of days trying to work out what I messed up, but can't for the life of me work it out.

I have a feeling I am doing something SUPER stupid!

```
e.stack:  Template render error: (events-pages:index.html)
  Template render error: (events-pages:index.html)
  Template render error: (events-pages:index.html)
  Template render error: (events-pages:index.html)
  Template render error: (events-pages:index.html)
  Template render error: (events-pages:index.html)
  Template render error: (events-pages:index.html)
  Template render error: (events-pages:index.html) [Line 18, Column 12]
  unknown block tag: item
    at Object.exports.prettifyError (/Users/username/website/node_modules/@apostrophecms/nunjucks/src/lib.js:34:15)
    at /Users/username/website/node_modules/@apostrophecms/nunjucks/src/environment.js:486:31
    at new_cls.root [as rootRenderFunc] (eval at _compile (/Users/username/website/node_modules/@apostrophecms/nunjucks/src/environment.js:565:24), <anonymous>:62:3)
    at new_cls.render (/Users/username/website/node_modules/@apostrophecms/nunjucks/src/environment.js:479:15)
    at Object.self.renderBody (/Users/username/website/node_modules/apostrophe/lib/modules/apostrophe-templates/index.js:318:47)
    at Object.self.renderForModule (/Users/username/website/node_modules/apostrophe/lib/modules/apostrophe-templates/index.js:179:19)
    at Object.self.render (/Users/username/website/node_modules/apostrophe/lib/modules/apostrophe-module/index.js:377:34)
    at /Users/username/website/node_modules/apostrophe/lib/modules/apostrophe-module/index.js:445:21
    at Object.self.renderPageForModule (/Users/username/website/node_modules/apostrophe/lib/modules/apostrophe-templates/index.js:697:21)
    at /Users/username/website/node_modules/apostrophe/lib/modules/apostrophe-module/index.js:575:31
    at /Users/username/website/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:726:13
    at /Users/username/website/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:52:16
    at /Users/username/website/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:269:32
    at /Users/username/website/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:44:16
    at /Users/username/website/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:723:17
    at /Users/username/website/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:167:37
    at /Users/username/website/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:52:16
    at iterate (/Users/username/website/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:260:24)
    at Object.async.forEachOfSeries.async.eachOfSeries (/Users/username/website/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:281:9)
    at Object.async.forEachSeries.async.eachSeries (/Users/username/website/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:214:22)
    at Object.self.loadDeferredWidgets (/Users/username/website/node_modules/apostrophe/lib/modules/apostrophe-areas/lib/api.js:538:18)
    at loadDeferredWidgets (/Users/username/website/node_modules/apostrophe/lib/modules/apostrophe-module/index.js:590:32)
:: 2020-10-15T18:27:23+0100: template error at /events
Current user: admin
Template render error: (events-pages:index.html)
  Template render error: (events-pages:index.html)
  Template render error: (events-pages:index.html)
  Template render error: (events-pages:index.html)
  Template render error: (events-pages:index.html)
  Template render error: (events-pages:index.html)
  Template render error: (events-pages:index.html)
  Template render error: (events-pages:index.html) [Line 18, Column 12]
  unknown block tag: item
    at Object.exports.prettifyError (/Users/username/website/node_modules/@apostrophecms/nunjucks/src/lib.js:34:15)
    at /Users/username/website/node_modules/@apostrophecms/nunjucks/src/environment.js:486:31
    at new_cls.root [as rootRenderFunc] (eval at _compile (/Users/username/website/node_modules/@apostrophecms/nunjucks/src/environment.js:565:24), <anonymous>:62:3)
    at new_cls.render (/Users/username/website/node_modules/@apostrophecms/nunjucks/src/environment.js:479:15)
    at Object.self.renderBody (/Users/username/website/node_modules/apostrophe/lib/modules/apostrophe-templates/index.js:318:47)
    at Object.self.renderForModule (/Users/username/website/node_modules/apostrophe/lib/modules/apostrophe-templates/index.js:179:19)
    at Object.self.render (/Users/username/website/node_modules/apostrophe/lib/modules/apostrophe-module/index.js:377:34)
    at /Users/username/website/node_modules/apostrophe/lib/modules/apostrophe-module/index.js:445:21
    at Object.self.renderPageForModule (/Users/username/website/node_modules/apostrophe/lib/modules/apostrophe-templates/index.js:697:21)
    at /Users/username/website/node_modules/apostrophe/lib/modules/apostrophe-module/index.js:575:31
    at /Users/username/website/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:726:13
    at /Users/username/website/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:52:16
    at /Users/username/website/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:269:32
    at /Users/username/website/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:44:16
    at /Users/username/website/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:723:17
    at /Users/username/website/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:167:37
    at /Users/username/website/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:52:16
    at iterate (/Users/username/website/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:260:24)
    at Object.async.forEachOfSeries.async.eachOfSeries (/Users/username/website/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:281:9)
    at Object.async.forEachSeries.async.eachSeries (/Users/username/website/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:214:22)
    at Object.self.loadDeferredWidgets (/Users/username/website/node_modules/apostrophe/lib/modules/apostrophe-areas/lib/api.js:538:18)
    at loadDeferredWidgets (/Users/username/website/node_modules/apostrophe/lib/modules/apostrophe-module/index.js:590:32) {
  name: 'Template render error'
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eugh, I knew I was being stupid, it's nothing to apostrophe!

It was my in nunchucks if statement! I had forgotten to put `elif` at the start of an expression so it caused an error.

It wasn't the easiest to work out from the error though!

what I had:

`{% item === 'date' %}`

what I needed:

`{% elif item === 'date' %}`